# Call MySQL stored procedure with parameter from batch file

Tags: mysql, batch-file

Do you know how to call a MySQL stored procedure from batch file?

Thank you ;)

I change my mind and I decided to create batch calling sql file :

My batch

```
@ECHO OFF
 cls


setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

SET MYSQL_EXE="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql.exe"
SET DB_USER=****
SET DB_PWD=***
SET DB=***

set DD=%DATE:~0,2%
set MM=%DATE:~3,2%
set YY=%DATE:~8,2%
set YYYY=%DATE:~6,4%
set HH=%TIME:~0,2%
set MN=%TIME:~3,2%

SET "CURRDAT=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD% %HH%:%MN%:00"



  FOR /F  %%f in ('DIR "K:\CRN\TRAVAIL\PROGRAMMATION\Prev Conso\csvPCE_PRECO\20140522\*.*" /B') DO (

      REM call stored procedure From MYSQL server
      del "C:\Users\7642FH\Local\fileTest.sql"
      ECHO USE pce; > C:\Users\7642FH\Local\fileTest.sql
      ECHO LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '!FILEPATHSQL!' >> C:\Users\7642FH\Local\fileTest.sql
      ECHO !TBL! >> C:\Users\7642FH\Local\fileTest.sql
      ECHO FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";" >> C:\Users\7642FH\Local\fileTest.sql
      ECHO LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' >> C:\Users\7642FH\Local\fileTest.sql
      ECHO IGNORE 1 ROWS >> C:\Users\7642FH\Local\fileTest.sql
      SET "VAR=(@var1,@var2,@var3)"
      ECHO !VAR! >> C:\Users\7642FH\Local\fileTest.sql
      ECHO !SQL! >> C:\Users\7642FH\Local\fileTest.sql
      CALL %MYSQL_EXE% --user=%DB_USER% --password=%DB_PWD% --database=%DB%    < C:\Users\7642FH\Local\fileTest.sql

)
```

And my sql

---

```
USE pce;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/7642FH/Local/RawFile/20141018/PREV_PCE_20141018_20141013_092802.csv' 
INTO TABLE tbl_pceraw
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";"
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@var1, @var2, @var3)
SET ElementId=@var1, TargetDateTime=!!,  CurrValue = REPLACE(@var3, ',', '.'), DataType='Actual', `TargetDate``TargetDateFolder``ComputeDateTime``ForcastValue``TargetFolder`;
```

I hope that it could be useful for someone !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MySQL command with an e option

**Command**

```
mysql -uDBUserName -pUserPassword -DDBName -e="CALL stored_procedure_name (param1, param2, ....)"
```

[Check this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/command-line-options.html)