# Import txt file to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, batch-file

I would like to import data from text file into SQL Server 2008. I have already done this with MySQL ([Call MySQL stored procedure with parameter from batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399645/call-mysql-store-procedure-with-parameter-from-batch-file)) I need to do this from batch.

This my SQL Server code so far

```
INSERT [pce].[dbo].[tlb_pce_actual]
  ([ElementId], [TargetDateTime], [CurrValue],[FolderDate],[FileDateTime],[FileName],[FolderPath],[ProcessDateTime])
   SELECT 
      BulkLoadFile.[IMPORTID],
      BulkLoadFile.[DT],
      [FolderDate] ='2014-05-19 00:00:00',
      [FileDateTime] ='2014-05-20 13:12:25',
      BulkLoadFile.[READING],
      [FileName]='CONSO_PCE_20140519_20140520_131225.csv',
      [FolderPath]='C:\Users\adminbi2\Downloads\Dsg_pce_raw_file\20140519',
      [ProcessDateTime]='2014-05-20 13:12:25'
   FROM  
      OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Users\********\Downloads\Dsg_pce_raw_file\20140519\CONSO_PCE_20140519_20140520_131225.csv',SINGLE_BLOB) AS BulkLoadFile
```

And the error message from SQL Server

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'IMPORTID'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Invalid column name 'DT'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   Invalid column name 'READING'.

`IMPORTID`, `DT` and `READING` are the first row of my file.

Here is the first rows of my text file

```
IMPORTID;DT;READING
A12250I2;19/05/2014 06:00;7,181
```

I need to get this (from mySQL) to SQL Server

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";"
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@var1, @var2, @var3)
SET ElementId=@var1, TargetDateTime=!!,  CurrValue = REPLACE(@var3, ',', '.'), DataType='Actual', `TargetDate``TargetDateFolder``ComputeDateTime``ForcastValue``TargetFolder`;
```

Regarding the batch

```
Calling MySQL
SET MYSQL_EXE="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql.exe"
SET DB_USER=****
SET DB_PWD=***
SET DB=***

CALL %MYSQL_EXE% --user=%DB_USER% --password=%DB_PWD% --database=%DB%    < C:\Users\7642FH\Local\fileTest.sql
```

Is it the same for SQL Server ?

Do you have any information guys !

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have access to SSIS?  That is probably the tool you ned to use.

Comment: Try use BULK INSERT
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms188365(v=sql.110).aspx